# how can I get the localhost IP for the ubuntu linux

Tags: linux

I want to setup a Linux server, but the first step is how can I get the localhost IP for the Linux, thus I can load this IP to show the page on another machine...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably belongs on serverfault but:

1. First off, calling it localhost is incorrect terminology.  Your localhost IP address is 127.0.0.1, which also happens to be my localhost IP address and most everyone else who doesn't get clever.
2. I'm assuming you meant the public IP address of the machine.  /sbin/ifconfig should give you that information, and there are also Graphical ways to get.  Are you looking to do this programatically or is that sufficient?  (Or ip addr since i keep forgetting ifconfig has been "deprecated")
3. Caveat one: depending on your web server (or other server), you may or may not need to modify your firewall and/or your settings so that it is served on your public IP address.  (Some servers, e.g. the django development server, default to only listening on your local interface and are therefore only accessible locally on that server and not to other servers.)
4. Caveat two: if you're running on a home network, you probably have a private IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.6); this is accessible to other computers on your home network but not to the outside world.  Enabling the latter generally requires enabling port forwarding which is a separate question and may or may not be allowed by your ISP.

Comment: Terminology must depend on context. In the Java runtime library, getLocalHost() and getLoopbackAddress() are distinct methods. getLoopbackAddress() always returns the loopback address which is what you're calling localhost. getLocalHost() essentially looks up the hostname and then gets the address for that, so it may return the external address. Just a bit of trivia.